# Xamarin - Fix 'Unfortunately, app has stopped' error on boot completed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created an app that calls boot completed class every time the phone restart. But my issue
is that I get a message that says '**Unfortunately, the app has stopped**' every time I restart the phone, especially on older phones like OS 4.4.2. What could cause this issue?

My code :

**Manifes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="mypackagename" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/shortcut_icon">
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".AppService" />
    <receiver android:name=".RebootListener" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**Boot completed class**

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class RebootListener : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        { 
           Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(AppService));
           context.StartService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
```

The issue persists even if I comment out the code in the OnReceive method. I presume the problem might be in the manifest file. If I remove the boot completed code in the manifest file I stop receiving this error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `receiver` from your manifest:

```
  <receiver android:name=".RebootListener" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
     ~~~~
  </intent-filter>
```

You have applied the `BroadcastReceiver` attribute to your `BroadcastReceiver` subclass and thus the `Xamarin.Android` build process will create this in your manifest automatically using a **MD5-based** Java class name (which will not be just `.RebootListener`)